# How to transform array with yielding a block?

Tags: ruby

I trying to define a helper method that takes the `Enumerable` as arguments and should return processed values. Look at example of my problem.

```
>> def bar
>>   yield(->(x) { x.nil? })
>> end
>> bar { [nil, nil, 1].reject }
=> #<Enumerator: [nil, nil, 1]:reject>
```

I can't understand. An example below works as expected:

```
>> [nil, nil, 1].reject { |x| x.nil? }
=> [1]
```

What is missing here? Why i get a `Enumerator` instance instead of result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The codeblock is not passed automagically to everything.

```
def bar 
   yield(->(x) { x.nil? })
end
bar do |p| 
  [nil, 1].reject &p
end
```

When you write

```
bar { ... }
```

you actually omit the yielded variable, exactly as in:

```
[1,nil].each { puts 'hey' }
```

Comment: This is a very useful answer!